# Finding vector positions for which values are close to the elements of another vector

Tags: arrays, r, vector

I want to find the positions (i.e. index) in a vector for which the values are the closest to another vector. For instance:

```
v1 <- c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5)
v2 <- c(0.1, 0.33, 0.98)
```

And I want to find a vector that contains the positions of v1 for which the values are as close as the elements of v2, that is:

```
# Desired output
v3 <- c(1, 2, 5) # since 0.1 is closest to 0, 0.33 is closest to 0.25, ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer to my own question. Here is the solution:

```
v1 <- c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5)
v2 <- c(0.1, 0.33, 0.98)
```

We will use the function **findInterval**

```
position <- findInterval(v2, v1) # result: c(1 2 4)
```

The problem is that we need to know if it is closer to the upper or lower bound. Hence we create a new vector dividing each interval by 2, and sort the vector:

```
v1p <- sort(c(v1, v1 - (v1 - shift(v1))/2)) # result:  c(0.000 0.125 0.250 0.375 0.500 0.625 0.750 0.875 1.000 1.125 1.250 1.375 1.500)

# Position in new vector
position_new <- findInterval(v2, v1p)

# Now if position is odd: lower bound, if position number is even: upper bound:
is.even <- function(x) x %% 2 == 0
final_position <- position + is.even(position_new)

print(final_position)
[1] 1 2 5
```